# About Kernel 4.16 compilation error

Tags: kernel, compiling

I install Ubuntu 16.04 on my new laptop Lenovo Ideapad 320. In that I try to compile new kernel version 4.16 while doing **make menuconfig** this error's are shown:

```
Unable to find the ncurses libraries or the required header files.
'make menuconfig' requires the ncurses libraries.

Install ncurses (ncurses-devel or libncurses-dev 
depending on your distribution) and try again.

scripts/kconfig/Makefile:206: recipe for target 'scripts/kconfig/dochecklxdialog' failed
make[1]: *** [scripts/kconfig/dochecklxdialog] Error 1
Makefile:514: recipe for target 'menuconfig' failed
make: *** [menuconfig] Error 2
```

After the I search through internet and I found that Ncurses want to install.   Then I install that also

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev
```

But result is same that is error..

Comment: Instead of compiling kernel by yourself you can install precomiled mainline kernel (see [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade)). If you really need to compile your kernel - see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel .

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your kind reply Vlad spirin

ya it also works

Then i found the solution for my compilation process

"sudo apt-get install --reinstall bison libbison-dev flex libfl-dev"

if i install the above package it work's fine.